# How to pass multiple model in view in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, view

Problem is: I want to run 3 different actions but instead of that i want to fed all data from single action in a bigger model.

I am using:

```
public class SearchScrapClass
    {
        public WClass WClass { get; set; }
        public SClass SClass { get; set; }
        public YClass YClass { get; set; }
    }

    public class WClass 
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
    }
    public class SClass 
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
    }
    public class YClass 
    {
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using LINQ to add data in these models.

I am using :

```
      var wikians = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='span']")
        from link in info.SelectNodes("div//a").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
         select new SearchScrapClass //Main Bigger Class
         {
            WClass.link= link.Attributes["href"].Value, //ERROR: How to add to WClass's url ?
            WClass.title= link.InnerText //ERROR: How to add to WClass's url ?
         }


var wikians = from info in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='results']")
               from link in info.SelectNodes("p//a").Where(x => x.Attributes.Contains("href"))
               select new SearchScrapClass //Main Bigger Class
                 {
                   YClass.link= link.Attributes["href"].Value, //ERROR: How to add to YClass's url ?
                   YClass.title= link.InnerText //ERROR: How to add to YClass's url ?
                 }

//Also for the 3rd class (model)


    return View(wikians); //and then return bigger class model so that i can access them in view
```

This is one way i want to add data to **link** and **title** of all the classes.

My try is to add data to all 3 classes from different sources and pass the bigger model to view so that i can access all the classes as:

```
@model SearchScrapClass
@using(Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.EditorFor(o => o.WClass.link)
    ...
}
```

Please suggest a way

Thanks

Comment: create a viewmodel that ties all three models together and type the view to that viewmodel.

Comment: I'm confused as to why you have 3 different classes that all look the same? Why not just use 3 different instances of the same class?

Comment: @hermiod : Actaully the logic i have shown looks similar [little modified] but the sources from where they fetch url and content is different. So i need different classes.

Comment: @Brian is correct. The "correct" way to do this in MVC is to create a ViewModel containing these three classes. The classes are data models. The ViewModel is something else, it should contain everything your View needs to render correctly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To Expand on my comment, I would suggest creating a ViewModel folder for organization sake.   in this add the view model

```
public class SearchScrapClassViewModel
{
    SearchScrapClass searchScrap;
    WClass wClass;
    SClass sClass;
    YClass yClass;
}
```

In your controller then you instantiate the new viewmodel

```
SearchScrapClassViewModel model = new SearchScrapClassViewModel
{
    ....add in your logic to fill your class objects here


}

return view(model);
```

then in your view add the using for the viewmodel.

```
@using SearchScrapClassViewModel
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the views side. How would I access each element w, s, y individually in the view?

Answer (score 1):

You can pass multiple model by creating a new model class which will contain multiple objects.

```
public class MultiModel 
    {
     SearchScrapClass searchScrap;
     WClass wClass;
     SClass sClass;
     YClass yClass;
    }
```

Comment: And then how do you receive / use that class in the view?

Comment: Brian has explain this further you can use Modal in view to access each class e.g. @Model.SearchScrapClass, Modal.WClasss

Answer (score 1):

See the tuple tutorial http://www.dotnetperls.com/tuple or this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx

Like controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var first = new FirstModel();
        var second = new SecondModel();
        return View(Tuple.Create(first,second));
    }
}
```

And the view:

@model Tuple

```
<div> 
    @Model.Item1.FirstModelProp
    @Model.Item2.SecondModelProp
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SearchScrapClassViewModel model = new SearchScrapClassViewModel
{
    ....add in your logic to fill your class objects here


}
```

what logic we apply here " ....add in your logic to fill your class objects here"